# Yii2 Gridview get all selected row for all pagination

Tags: yii, yii2

I wrapped my gridview with Pjax widget like this

```
 \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();
    gridview
 \yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
```

in order to make the gridview make ajax request when I click on each pagination.

I also use  `['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],` in column as well.
and I find that when I'm on first pagination I checked some rows and then go to second page and check some rows but when I go back to first page what I've checked is gone.
My question is how can I keep all checkedrow for all pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With current conditions (Pjax, multiple pages, `yii\grid\CheckboxColumn`) it's impossible because of the way it works.

When you click on the pagination links all `GridView` html content is replaced by new one that comes from the AJAX response.

So obviously all selected checkboxes on the previous page are gone.

Few possible ways to solve that:

**1)** Write custom javascript and server side logic.

As one of the options, you can send AJAX request to server with parameter meaning that user has chosen to select all data for the bulk delete operation (or use separate controller action for bulk deletion). In this case actually we don't need to get the selected data from user, because we can simply get them from database (credits - [Seng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959939/seng)).

**2)** Increase number of displayed rows per page.

**3)** Use infinite scroll extension, for example [this](http://kop.github.io/yii2-scroll-pager/).

**4)** Break desired action in several iterations:

- select needed rows on first page, do action (for example, delete).
- repeat this again for other pages.

You can get selected rows like that:

```
$('#your-grid-view').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

Comment: could you tell me how can I customize code on pjax event after click pagination?

Comment: It's too broad. Questions like that ("write my code for me") are not welcomed on SO. Try something and add some drafts at least. But I recommend to use alternatives that I desribed (infinite scroll or break into steps).

Comment: Thanks I know how to do it now.

Comment: Glad to help. If it's helpful, you can upvote as well.

Comment: Why do you think it impossible? Why don't simply pass a data to server that user has chosen to select all for the bulk operation. We don't need to get the selected data from user when choosing "all", but we can simply get them from database. right?

Comment: @SenG I mean it's not "impossible at all", it's impossible according to given conditions - with Pjax, multiple pages and `CheckboxColumn`. Your suggestion is special case of point 1 (write custom js). But I added specification and your example, thanks for remark.

Comment: $('#your-grid-view').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows'); its showing empty\

Answer (score 1):

[infinite scroll] : http://kop.github.io/yii2-scroll-pager/ will work good if you do not have any pjax filters. If you have filters also in play, do not use this plugin as it does not support pjax filters with it. For rest of the applications it is perfect to use.

Update1 : it seems to be straight forward than expected, here is the how I accomplished it

Add following lines to the checkbox column

```
'checkboxOptions' => function($data){
                        return ['id' => $data->id, 'onClick' => 'selectedRow(this)'];
                    }
```

Now add following JS to the common js file you will have in your project of the page where this datagrid resides

```
var selectedItems=[]; //global variable
/**
 * Store the value of the selected row or delete it if it is unselected
 * 
 * @param {checkbox} ele 
 */
function selectedRow(ele){
    if($(ele).is(':checked')) {
        //push the element
        if(!selectedItems.includes($(ele).attr('id'))) {
            selectedItems.push($(ele).attr('id'));
        }
    } else {
        //pop the element
        if(selectedItems.includes($(ele).attr('id'))) {
            selectedItems.pop($(ele).attr('id'));
        }
    }
}
```

Above function will store the selected row ids in the global variable array

Now add following lines to pjax:end event handler

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function () {
    //Select the already selected items on the grid view
    if(!empty(selectedItems)){
        $.each(selectedItems, function (index,value) {
            $("#"+value).attr('checked',true);
        });
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The pjax:end event handler gives an Uncaught ReferenceError: empty is not defined.
You can change the if-statement with `if (selectedItems.length !== 0)`

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this problem and it works properly with Pjax.

You may use my CheckboxColumn. I hope this can help. The checked items are recorded with cookies.

You can read the part with //add by hezll to understand how to fix it, because I didn't provide a complete general one.

Hope it works for you.

https://owncloud.xiwangkt.com/index.php/s/dGH3fezC5MGCx4H